# What you shouldn't do when solving a puzzle

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, lateral-thinking, knowledge

> *You can't see
>
>   Literally
>
>   But if you watch me
>
>   You might cry like a baby
>
>   **and be motivated to play rugby***
>
> *I'm a necessary distraction
>
>   sometimes a big explosion
>
>   If I ever got one over my ex
>
>   You'll know who I am*
>
> *I'm always consistent
>
>   Even if you change my content
>
>   **Order me around, I promise I won't byte**
>
>   Now add 3 to make me a gerund
>
>   Then add 1 to make me more*
>
> *Now you have three, onto the final spree
>
>   Get the next trio of three
>
>   and I'll give you this for free
>
>   what's 0 multiplied by 83*?

**Hint for third stanza:**

> You can find me in most books
>  but not in some dictionaries
>  Now add 3 to *the end* make me a noun
>  Then add 1 to *the end* make me more 
>  i.e. bomb $\rightarrow$ bomb**ing** $\rightarrow$ bombing**s**

**Hint for second stanza:**

> Think math for 3rd line
>  This doesn't lead to the word immediately, use 1st and 2nd lines to figure out the intended word

*correction added, I meant noun not verb.*
*clarified further, I meant gerund*
*added extra lines for hints of 1st and 3rd stanzas*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many hints and answers I decided to make an account since I feel like I can get some of the answers.

*You can't see

Literally*

> Blind

*But if you watch me

You might cry like a baby

and be motivated to play rugby*

> After googling "blind rugby" I couldn't find anything, but based on @Karun Kamal's answer, changing it to "blind rugby movie" lead to the movie **Blindside**.

*OP added **necessary** to distraction, and a big explosion*

> I would say diversion

*If I got one over my ex*

> Thinking along the lines of math all I have is 1/x which is indeed divergent (harmonic series) Confirming my first guess **diversion**

*I'm always consistent

Even if you change my content

Order me around, I promise I won't byte*

> If the "byte" is intentional, then this must be referring to some sort of programming language? or CS in general.
> This is probably hinting at a list index, if you change the contents of a list, the first element will always have 0th index... etc.

*You can find me in most books

but not in some dictionaries*

> From that I can conclude that this is most likely **index** because most books have indexes but dictionaries (e.g. in python) don't have indexes, they have keys.

*Add 3 to make me a gerund and add 1 to make me more*

> Simple and straightforward, Index $\rightarrow$ Indexing $\rightarrow$ **Indexings**

**UPDATE**

Ok I think I got it.

*Now you have three, onto the final spree*

> Most probably referring to these:
>  Blindside, Diversion and Indexings

*Get the next thrio of three*

> With a bit of analyzing, I noticed those 3 words above are semi-anagrams of the word **inside**, with an extra 3 letters.
>  That is **bl**insi**d**e, di**v**e**r**si**o**n and inde**x**i**ng**s . 
>  Which gave me **bld, vro** and **xng**.

*What's 0 multiplied by 83?*

> Solved by @Mea Culpa Nay 0x83 $\rightarrow$ hex for 131
>  Which gives **b**ld vr**o** **x**ng $\rightarrow$ box

So my answer is:

> Since "box" was found in "inside", this lead me to the famous anti-phrase.
>  **Think inside the box.**
>  Which is definitely not what you want to do when solving the puzzle.

Comment: Closest one so far! Good work!, Now use the last stanza to its fullest and get the answer~

Comment: You got it! You don't mind if I edit this to keep the format consistent do you?

Comment: Not at all @JFox

Answer (score 4):

You can't see
Literally
But if you watch me
You might cry like a baby

> nightmare

I'm a distraction
sometimes a big explosion
If I ever got one over my ex
You'll know who I am

> noise (bomb explosion, commotion is synonym for noise)

I'm always consistent
Even if you change my content
Now add 3 to make me a verb
Then add 1 more to make me a noun

> drink, drinking, grandkids

Now you have three, onto the final spree
Get the next trio of three
and I'll give you this for free
what's 0 multiplied by 83?

> $0 \times 83 =0, $ take "er" from "zero"

Answer

> DINNER, you should not make or have dinner while solving a puzzle

Now give me my free

> DINNER

**EDIT: backtracking, starting with Hints**

> Since Hints are none and "sister" is synonym for "nun", trying to fit "sister"

You can't see
Literally
But if you watch me
You might cry like a baby

> Sin

I'm a distraction
sometimes a big explosion
If I ever got one over my ex
You'll know who I am

> Insult

I'm always consistent
Even if you change my content
Now add 3 to make me a verb
Then add 1 more to make me a noun

> Sea, sneak, snakes

Now you have three, onto the final spree
Get the next trio of three
and I'll give you this for free
what's 0 multiplied by 83?

> Nothing is free, zero is nothing, taker "er" from "zero"

Finally,

> Adding "t" we get "SISTER", anagram is RESITS, very near to this word is "RECITE", which means you shouldn't speak aloud your thought process while solving a puzzle

Comment: Well, @Vikram, how a nightmare is linked with dinner...wondering...if the stuff in the dinner can cause nightmare...:-)

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay, take first letter of nightmare, noise, drink, add "er" to it

Comment: The way you're solving the puzzle is correct, each stanza yields one word. Except for the last stanza, it's just clues on the approach to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

You are

> A BLANK

You can't see
Literally

> You cannot see a blank space

But if you watch me
You might cry like a baby

> I think the first half of each stanza refers to the answer and the second half is clues to each letter in the answer. Somehow this is a clue that the first letter is A

I'm a distraction
sometimes a big explosion

> A blank fired in a gun makes an explosion

If I ever got one over my ex
You'll know who I am

> One letter past A (the previous letter in answer) is B

I'm always consistent
Even if you change my content

> If you fill in a blank ______ in a sentence then the sentence still makes sense.

Now add 3 to make me a verb
Then add 1 more to make me a noun

> L. Add three to get O (owe) add one more to get P (pea)

Now you have three, onto the final spree
Get the next trio of three
and I'll give you this for free
what's 0 multiplied by 83?

> If you get ANK, then you have A BLANK and also get the answer to 0*83

Comment: Nice job. I like it. Hopefully its right.

Comment: If the answer was a word this would definitely be it! +1

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be

**Hint**

As it cannot be seen literally. But after looking at it one regrets.(cry like a baby)

---

As the heading of this puzzle also depicts towards not looking at it whilst solving a puzzle.

Comment: Clever, but sadly the first stanza does not give the word "hint".

Comment: Or is it the SUN....??

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Day-Dreaming ?

You can't see
Literally
But if you watch me
You might cry like a baby

> A dream we cannot see literally (meaning with eyes open ). A nightmare, if watched with eyes open can make us cry (like a child).

I'm a distraction
sometimes a big explosion
If I ever got one over my ex
You'll know who I am

> An occurrence of dream is a symbol of disturbed sleep and hence a kind of distraction of mind even in the sleep ! Later part need to be explained ...

I'm always consistent
Even if you change my content
Now add 3 to make me a verb
Then add 1 more to make me a noun

> A dream is said to occur for atmost 30s (in any case)irrespective of subject. Add 3 letters 'D', 'A', 'Y' to it to get Day-dream : a verb and adding 't' makes it Dreamt, a verb.

Now you have three, onto the final spree
Get the next trio of three
and I'll give you this for free
what's 0 multiplied by 83?

> Day-dreaming is usually referred as one's imagination and  '0 multiplied by 83' is 0x83, which is 83 in Hexadecimal and equal to 131 in decimal system. 131 stands for an abbreviated form of 'I Owe You' to 'I Owe U' ?!

And as per the title of the puzzle, one should not

> Day-dream

while solving puzzles

Comment: Correct on the 0 x 83 ! it is indeed 131. But you need to get the trio of three to make sense of that.

Comment: @JFox, provided an explanation, what I thought.

Comment: Sorry, aside from 131, the rest will lead you nowhere. Try and see @Vikram's answer

Comment: I had the same answer after reading the first parah, but rest of the puzzle doesnt explain it well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be

> ZERO / Nothing

Following the stanzas:
You can't see
Literally
But if you watch me
You might cry like a baby

> We can't the zero, which is nothing. But if someone get zero in exam or anywhere, where number matters, s/he might cry after that.

I'm a distraction
sometimes a big explosion
If I ever got one over my ex
You'll know who I am

> Having nothing could be a reason for distraction for people. And ex should be 1 for zero and if we put the zero after 1 many times, could get a lot of things or exploit money. Or we could also refer the "full" as an ex of nothing and if we use anything more then its full limit could make a explosion in case.

I'm always consistent
Even if you change my content
Now add 3 to make me a verb
Then add 1 more to make me a noun

> Zero is always consistent as nothing to change in its content. Adding 'ing' to zero gives zeroing and its a verb. Not sure about the next line though. Might be referring to NIL.

Now you have three, onto the final spree
Get the next trio of three
and I'll give you this for free
what's 0 multiplied by 83?

> ZERO, Nothing, ZEROING all along with 83 * 0 gives a big 0 as an answer of this puzzle.

This could also help others to solve it, if this is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a >>>

> MOVIE

You can't see Literally,
But if you watch me

> Technically , see mean to be aware of what is around you by using your eyes and we Watch a movie, as in Watch is deliberately looking at something for a period of time (like a MOVIE)

You might cry like a baby

> Horror movies can make you cry like a baby

and be motivated to play rugby

> A movie can do that for rugby (like INVICTUS) or for the other sports too!

I'm a necessary distraction

> People go to movies to distract themselves.

sometimes a big explosion

> you can see an explosion in a movie

If I ever got one over my ex
You'll know who I am

> movie can be made on EX and you come to know about the person

I'm always consistent

> So many movies been released worldwide consistently.

Even if you change my content

> Different genre

Order me around, I promise I won't byte

> you can order a movie without the fear of byte

Now add 3 to make me a gerund

> (not able to make a noun  )

Then add 1 to make me more

> MOVIE(S)

Now you have three, onto the final spree

> like a seasons ?

Get the next trio of three
and I'll give you this for free

> discounts (Yay!!)

what's 0 multiplied by 83?

> 0 * 83 is Zero (Pretty sure, its a  Movie)

Answer (score -2):

The answer is

> Fat Indian Guy

Because

> You cant see him unless you visit his house

But

> If you see him you will cry for fitness.

Comment: Fat Country Guy... could be a better expression @Marodian ...:-)

Comment: Why the downvote? Its supposed to be my answer right? I think it is fat indian guy, why are you downvoting an opinion. Lol